# on tab hit show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that shows a div onclick, however I want the same logic to occur when the user hits the tab button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#password").click(function(){
        $("#password-confirm").slideDown(600);
    });
});
```

Can this function be used for a tab button? If so, how?

Comment: Can you post the portion of your HTML that you are mentioning?

Comment: Try setting tabs visible and hidden through js and css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to detect tab key from password field. You can try this:

```
$("#password").keydown(function (e) { 
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

  if (keyCode == 9) { 
    $("#password").trigger("click"); // trigger click event 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Please add some description to be useful for beginners.+1 for nice answer.

Comment: Lovely! Just what i was after

Answer (score 0):

set your div's tabindex property eg: `<div tabindex="0">`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#password").on("click focus", function(){
        $("#password-confirm").slideDown(600);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").keydown(function(e){
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
    if (keyCode == 9) { 
        $("#password-confirm").slideDown(600);
    }
});
```